# Changing CSS URL for pointer cursor (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

I asked a question yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394095/change-cursor-image-css-url-using-javascript) about having a cursor that changes regularly using javascript, to make it look animated. I got a great answer (Thank you Shiva!). I've now been trying to get two different 'animated' cursors, one for the 'auto' cursor, and a different one for the 'pointer' cursor.

I tried it lots of different ways, but just can't work it out (I must admit,  I'm completely new to this - trying to improve). Here's one of the ways I tried to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">   
var images = [
'assets/shared/cursors/drum1.cur',
'assets/shared/cursors/drum2.cur',
'assets/shared/cursors/drum3.cur',
'assets/shared/cursors/drum4.cur'
];

var x = 0;

function displayNextImage() {
x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
document.body.style.cursor = 'url("' + images[x] + '"), default';
} 

setInterval(displayNextImage, 250);
</script>

<script type = "text/javascript">   
var images = [
'assets/shared/cursors/point1.cur',
'assets/shared/cursors/point2.cur',
'assets/shared/cursors/point3.cur',
'assets/shared/cursors/point4.cur'
];

var x = 0;

function displayNextImage() {
x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
document.body.style.cursor:pointer = 'url("' + images[x] + '"), default';
} 

setInterval(displayNextImage, 250);
</script>

<body>

<div style="height: 1000vh; width: 1000vw;"></div>
</body>
</html>
</head>
</html>
```

If possible I'd like to do it without jQuery.

Again, any help is really appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: do you wanna have the cursor changing or only the pointer cursor ?

Comment: The normal cursor is already 'animated' how I want it. I'm happy with that. What I want is a different 'animated' cursor while the mouse is over (or clicking on) a link, and then back to the normal 'animated' cursor.

Comment: Then you must do similar things but binding an over event each interval (deleting any already bind one) that will use the next image

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery for this :

```
var images = [
  'assets/shared/cursors/point1.cur',
  'assets/shared/cursors/point2.cur',
  'assets/shared/cursors/point3.cur',
  'assets/shared/cursors/point4.cur'
];

var x = 0;

function changeLinkCursorHoverBinding(){
  $("a").hover(function(){/*this is the mouseenter triggered function*/
    $(this).css("cursor",'url("' + images[x] + '"), default');
  }, function(){
    //handle mouseleave here if needed
  });

  x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;//put at the end to start at 0

  setTimeout(changeLinkCursorHoverBinding, 250);
}

$(document).ready(changeLinkCursorHoverBinding);//initial call of the function
```

EDIT

Or without jQuery :

```
var images = [
  'assets/shared/cursors/point1.cur',
  'assets/shared/cursors/point2.cur',
  'assets/shared/cursors/point3.cur',
  'assets/shared/cursors/point4.cur'
];

var x = 0;

function changeLinkCursorHoverBinding(){
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a");
 elems.removeEventListener("mouseenter", onHover);
 elems.removeEventListener("mouseleave", offHover);

 elems.addEventListener("mouseenter", onHover);
 elems.addEventListener("mouseleave", offHover);

 x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x+1;

 setTimeout(changeLinkCursorHoverBinding, 250);
}

function onHover(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for(e in elems){
    e.style.cursor = "url('" + images[x] + "'), default";
  }//you can use the regular for loop here if you wanna
}

function offHover(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for(e in elems){
    /*handle mouseleave here*/
  }
}
```

I had to name EH functions (and remove EH each call) because I wasn't sure that `addEventListener` overrides same handler if called again.

EDIT

for non jQuery way, you need to add `onload="changeLinkCursorHoverBinding()"` on your `<body>` tag this way :
`<body onload="changeLinkCursorHoverBinding()">` (the initial call after page's load).

Comment: Thank you Vivick. I'll try this out if no one has another idea, but if possible I'd like to do it without jQuery (sorry, I should have said this in my question).

Comment: I'll edit my answer to add a non jQuery version of it

Comment: Thank you so much Vivick. I've tried it, but can't get it to work. I must just be doing something stupid. Here's what I've done https://pastebin.com/Mtd5F7a7 - Can you see where I've gone wrong?

Comment: try to remove `for(e in elems)` by `for(e of elems)` or the regular for loop `for(var i = 0 ; i < elems.length ; i++)`.

If you use the last one you need to use `elems[i]` instead of `e` to refer to the current element in the loop.

Comment: Oh and remove the first script part otherwise it could lead to name collisions

Comment: Still havn't been able to work out what I'm doing wrong. I'm going to get the rest of the site done, and then I'll have another go at this. Thank you for your help Vivick. I'll update if I get it working.